# Центрирование двух div при использовании float

Tags: html, css, float

Есть данный код:

```css
.div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Как видите два div-а прижаты к левому краю несмотря на `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`. Если убрать `float: left` div-ы центрируются как надо. Мой вопрос: Можно ли не убирая   `float` центрировать div-ы?

Comment: а зачем Вам float, если Вы хотите центрировать блоки? какую роль он играет?

Comment: Мне надо чтобы блоки были в одну линию но при этом по центру.

Comment: Сделайте им блок-обёртку и задайте ему display:flex; justify-content: center. Тогда они будут в одну линию и в центре.

Comment: Либо задайте блокам display: inline-block, а родительской обёртке - text-align: center (но решение на флексе более современное, если так можно выразиться)

Comment: Первый вариант помог. Огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: Float - это свойство CSS для позиционирования элементов. В веб-дизайне, элементы страницы с установленным свойством float, ведут себя точно также как и изображения в полиграфии, когда текст "обтекает" их. По сути он изначально не подходит, если мы хотим сделать блоки по середине.